# How to match certain text in returned XPath HTML?

Tags: ruby, xpath

I am using Xpath in Ruby with following statement.

```
print XPath.first(Document.new(html),"//tr[@id='ctl00_c1_rr_ci_trAdd']//td[2]")
```

The Query return the following text.

```
<td>

                1371 N Belsay Rd<br/>Burton, MI 48509
                <br/>
                <a href='http://www.mapquest.com/maps/map.adp?style=2&amp;address=1371+N+Belsay+Rd&amp;city=Burton&amp;state=MI&amp;zip=48509' class='rptLnk2' id='ctl00_c1_rr_ci_hlMapQuest' target='_blank'>See the location on a Mapquest Map</a>
                <br/>
                <a href='http://maps.google.com?q=1371+N+Belsay+Rd Burton, MI 48509' class='rptLnk2' id='ctl00_c1_rr_ci_hlGoogleMaps' target='_blank'>See the location on a Google Map</a>
            </td>
```

But I just want this text

```
1371 N Belsay Rd<br/>Burton, MI 48509
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this? When I am using scan statement - I am getting this error.

```
private method `scan' called for <td> ... </>:REXML::Element (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XPath expression to get this text `1371 N Belsay Rd` -- as a text node, is:

```
((//tr[@id='ctl00_c1_rr_ci_trAdd'])//td)[2]/text()[1]
```

In case you want the expression to select the three nodes:

```
1371 N Belsay Rd<br/>Burton, MI 48509
```

you may use this one:

```
normalize-space(((//tr[@id='ctl00_c1_rr_ci_trAdd'])//td)
                              [2]
                                /node()[not(position() > 3)])
```

Comment: It only returns `1371 N Belsay Rd` and not `1371 N Belsay Rd<br/>Burton, MI 48509`

Comment: @Shubham: Sorry I hadn't read well your question. I have edited my answer and now you have the XPath expression that selects exactly the nodes you are asking for.